# Image duplication after multiple file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, image-uploading, onload

Have this issue here: I want to upload several images at once and show them directly afterwards in the browser. Everything is fine. However, doing this on mobile, sometimes I don't get all the images, but duplicates of another one from the file array. I have a suspicion, that this has to do with hardware limitations, since on PC everything works fine, but not on mobile.

[Here is the fiddle. You can check it via mobile to see if duplicates appear.](http://jsfiddle.net/bjvmahL1/)

So in result I get this on mobile. It wasn't two images in the selection, only one:

[image: After file input several images, I get a duplicate of an image in place of another actual selected image]

Here I have the Javascript snippet. Is there any room for improvement? Espacially onload processes are really confusing me from time to time. Is there any chance to write it better?

***Javascript:***

```
jQuery('.upload-mobile').change(function(){
    jQuery('body').toggleClass( "loading" );
    var imagecounter = jQuery(this)[0].files.length;
    var loadcounter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<imagecounter;i++){
        for(var p = 1;p<=12;p++){
            if(jQuery('#preview'+p).length<=0){
                jQuery('.image-collection').prepend(jQuery('<div></div>',{id:'preview'+p,css:{'display':'inline-block'}}));
                break;
            };
        }
        var file = this.files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){  
                for(var w = 1;w<=12;w++){
                    if(jQuery('#preview'+w).children().length>0) {

                    }
                    else{
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                        img.id = 'img'+w;
                        img.className += " img-responsive";
                        img.className += " border-blue";
                        img.className += " image-small";
                        img.className += " image-cover";
                        img.style.display='none';
                        document.getElementById("preview"+w).appendChild(img);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                loadcounter++;
                if(loadcounter==imagecounter){
                    var count = jQuery('.image-collection').children().length;
                    jQuery('.image-small').delay('1500').fadeIn('3000', function(){
                        jQuery('#image-counter').text(count+'/12');
                        jQuery('body').removeClass( "loading" );
                        if( jQuery('#image-counter').text()=='12/12'){
                            jQuery('#upload-photos').fadeOut('200', function(){
                                jQuery('#three-cube-compact').fadeIn('200');
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }   
        };

        var image = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to use the forEach function. I didn't use the for each loops earlier, so I can not say much about the difference between foreach and for. I can't say if it works better or not, but I have seen less duplicates (maybe I didn't check to often to asume good functionality of it). It almost works, but maybe there is another way to make it work flawlessly?

***Javascript:***

```
jQuery('.upload-mobile').change(function(){
    jQuery('body').toggleClass( "loading" );
    var imagecounter = jQuery(this)[0].files.length;
    var loadcounter = 0;
    Array.from(this.files).forEach(function (image, index){
        for(var p = 1;p<=12;p++){
            if(jQuery('#preview'+p).length<=0){
                jQuery('.image-collection').prepend(jQuery('<div></div>',{id:'preview'+p,css:{'display':'inline-block'}}));

                break;
            };
        };
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
                for(var w = 1;w<=12;w++){
                    if(jQuery('#preview'+w).children().length>0) {

                    }
                    else{
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                        img.id = 'img'+w;
                        img.className += " img-responsive";
                        img.className += " border-blue";
                        img.className += " image-small";
                        img.className += " image-cover";
                        img.style.display='none';
                        document.getElementById("preview"+w).appendChild(img);

                        break;
                    }
                }
                loadcounter++;
                if(loadcounter==imagecounter){
                    var count = jQuery('.image-collection').children().length;
                    jQuery('.image-small').delay('1500').fadeIn('3000', function(){
                        jQuery('#image-counter').text(count+'/12');
                        jQuery('body').removeClass( "loading" );
                        if( jQuery('#image-counter').text()=='12/12'){
                            jQuery('#upload-photos').fadeOut('200', function(){
                                jQuery('#three-cube-compact').fadeIn('200');
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
        };
        var pic = reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    });
});
```

**EDIT2:**

[The fiddle was updated](http://jsfiddle.net/bjvmahL1/2/)

**EDIT3:**

Added an image of the mobile screen. I also figured out it might has something to do with the file explorer on the mobile device. When I select using the first file explorer, I don't get the duplication bug:

[image: Mobile File Explorer that appears first. Using it does not create the bug]

However, by clicking on Browse ("Durchsuchen" on the image), I get to another file explorer. And using that one creates this "duplication bug":

[image]

Is there maybe a way to solve this or maybe to disable the Browse button?

Comment: I tested it with Opera in my phone. I see what's happening here. The old image preview remains while the new ones append to the list. Perhaps you should clear out the preview when the file upload starts (soon as the process begins where you check for files).

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gd8qy4wt/

Comment: Thanks for your inout @YousofK. Actually it is ok that the images appear afterwards. Further on you can also delete some of them. The main issue is, that when uploading many images at once, some of them are ignored and are replaced with another image that already was "inserted" before. If you upload 12 at once, you will see, that you will get some duplicates. You will get overall 12 images, but some of them aren't in and are replaced as duplicates. I post a picture later.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue with my phone, but couldn't. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Can you check if using `let` instead of `var` solves it? I was running into a similar issue and that was a solution for me. Also there was an issue with the loop I was doing in the instance before that.

Comment: Where exactly? I was checking in on `let img = document.createElement("img");` but didn't work either.
To replicate the issue you need to try out 12 images and do it maybe several times refreshing the whole page.
**EDIT:** I see, that the other file explorer is actually the google photos app. Maybe with this you could replicate it...

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. On my phone, it uploads only one file, even though I selected multiples.

Comment: Even though you are right, I have also the same problem with goole photos, but I was wrong here too. The second file explorer was actually not from google photos, but from the mobile OS. I am using a Samsung A5.
I tried this on google chrome and samsung internet app. Both had the same issue. The firefox app can't handle multiple images